# Connecting MS_SQL DB IN asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, connection

I was trying to connectMs_sql database in asp.net but server error of network path not found... it is not able to establish connection to sql server...comes while in gridview it is taking it as sqldatasource perfectly

Comment: Additional details will make it easier for someone to provide a helpful answer. Check out [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some great tips. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This for customized class to call the ADO.Net. Please use this and let me know if you have any doubts.

```
public class DbConnectionHelper {
   public DataSet DBConnection(string TableName, SqlParameter[] p, string Query, CommandType cmdText) {
    string connString = @ "your connection string here";
    //Object Declaration
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    try {
     //Get Connection string and Make Connection
     con.ConnectionString = connString; //Get the Connection String
     if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed) {
      con.Open(); //Connection Open
     }
     if (cmdText == CommandType.StoredProcedure) //Type : Stored Procedure
     {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cmd.CommandText = Query;
      if (p.Length > 0) // If Any parameter is there means, we need to add.
      {
       for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++) {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p[i]);
       }
      }
     }
     if (cmdText == CommandType.Text) // Type : Text
     {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      cmd.CommandText = Query;
     }
     if (cmdText == CommandType.TableDirect) //Type: Table Direct
     {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      cmd.CommandText = Query;
     }
     cmd.Connection = con; //Get Connection in Command
     sda.SelectCommand = cmd; // Select Command From Command to SqlDataAdaptor
     sda.Fill(ds, TableName); // Execute Query and Get Result into DataSet
     con.Close(); //Connection Close
    } catch (Exception ex) {

     throw ex; //Here you need to handle Exception
    }
    return ds;
   }
  }
```